# Clean way to read a null-terminated (C-style) string from a file?

Tags: python, string, null, python-2.x, c-strings

I'm looking for a clean and simple way to read a null-terminated C string from a file or file-like object in Python. In a way that doesn't consume more input from the file than it needs, or pushes it back onto whatever file/buffer it works with such that other code can read the data immediately after a null-terminated string.

I've seen [a bit of rather ugly code](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/41987-canonical-way-dealing-null-separated-lines) to do it, but not much that I'd like to use.

[universal newlines support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) only works for `open()`ed files, not StringIO objects etc, and doesn't look like it handles unconventional newlines. Also, if it did work it'd result in strings with `\n` appended, which is undesirable.

[struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) [doesn't look like it supports reading arbitrary-length C strings at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26060110/398670), requiring a length as part of the format.

[ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) has `c_buffer`, which can be constructed from a byte string and will return the first null terminated string as its `value`. Again, this requires determining how much must be read in advance, and it doesn't differentiate between null-terminated and unterminated strings. The same is true of `c_char_p`. So it doesn't seem to help much, since you already have to know you've read enough of the string and have to handle buffer splits.

The usual way to do this in C is read chunks into a buffer, copying and resizing the buffer if needed, then check if the newest chunk read contains a null byte. If it does, return everything up to the null byte and either realign the buffer or if you're being fancy, keep on reading and use it as a ring buffer. (This only works if you can hand the excess data read back to the caller, or if your platform's `ungetc` lets to push a lot back onto the file, of course.)

Is it necessary to spell out similar code in Python? I was surprised not to find anything canned in `io`, `ctypes` or `struct`.

file objects don't seem to have a way to push back onto their buffer, like `ungetc`, and neither do buffered I/O streams in the `io` module.

I feel like I must be missing the obvious here. I'd really rather avoid byte-by-byte reading:

```
def readcstr(f):
    buf = bytearray()
    while True:
        b = f.read(1)
        if b is None or b == '\0':
            return str(buf)
        else:
            buf.append(b)
```

but right now that's what I'm doing.

Comment: I don't think there is anything builtin for this.  You could use chunks if you keep track of your position in the file and use `seek` to seek to the position right after the null byte.

Comment: If you can do without support for arbitrary file-like objects, only supporting true, mmap-able file objects, I'd recommend bypassing file read/write and using the [`mmap` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html). It would allow you to use the [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap.find) method to begin at an arbitrary start point and determine where the next `b'\0'` is, then slice out that part of the mapping into a Py2 `str` (Py3 `bytes`) directly. Failing that, eager `read` and `seek`-ing back are the only meaningfully distinct approaches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Incredibly mild improvement on what you have (mostly in that it uses more built-ins that, in CPython, are implemented in C, which usually runs faster):

```
import functools
import itertools

def readcstr(f):
    toeof = iter(functools.partial(f.read, 1), '')
    return ''.join(itertools.takewhile('\0'.__ne__, toeof))
```

This is relatively ugly (and sensitive to the type of the file object; it won't work with file objects that return `unicode`), but pushes all the work to the C layer. The two arg iter ensures you stop if the file is exhausted, while `itertools.takewhile` looks for (and consumes) the `NUL` terminator but no more; `''.join` then combines the bytes read into a single return value.

Comment: Nice. Thankyou, that's a clear way to express what the function does. No idea of joining a series of strings is better or worse than using a bytearray, but *shrug*. I'm not trying to micro-optimize.

Comment: Whoops, and I didn't accept your answer. Hilariously I just found this... when searchin ffor info on the same problem again. Weird that Python doesn't offer tools for this via `struct` or via the `io` module